# CSS files stopped displaying on the page after connecting the Bootstrap library

Tags: html

After downloading the Bootstrap library, the CSS files stopped responding to index.html, they are not displayed on the page. Please explain what could be wrong. I'm just a beginner in this area and I don't know what it might be. Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="box"></div>  

.box {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more on the problem? Also add CSS code inside `<style>
.box {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 50px;
} 
</style>` tags.

Comment: Спасибо я уже разобрался в проблеме, просто у меня не в той папке лежал index.html и поэтому он не реагировал на CSS-стили